Query dynamic fields from DB with requested fields on GraphQL query
I'm trying to fetch GraphQL requested fields on DB using Criteria API, but when a look in debug or print the class every fields from my MediaModel class as being fetched.
public abstract class Utils {
    public static Map<String, List<String>> getRequestedFields(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
        return environment.getSelectionSet().getFields().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        SelectedField::getName,
                        field -> field.getSelectionSet().getFields().stream()
                                .map(SelectedField::getName)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
}

This util method get requested fields and subfields from GraphQL into a Map.
Example:
query Media {
    tvserie(name: "Stranger Things") {
       id
       title
       genres {
         name
       }
    }
}

Will turn into this JSON:
{
  "media": [
    "id",
    "title",
    "genres"
  ],
  "genres": [
    "name"
  ]
}

My repository:
@Repository
public class MediaRepositoryCustomImpl implements MediaRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<MediaModel> findMediaByNameOrAlternativeTitleAndMediaCategory(
            String name,
            String alternativeTitle,
            Integer category,
            Map<String, List<String>> requestedFields) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<MediaModel> query = cb.createQuery(MediaModel.class);
        Root<MediaModel> mediaRoot = query.from(MediaModel.class);
        Join<MediaModel, AlternativeTitleModel> altTitlesJoin = mediaRoot.join("alternativeTitles", JoinType.LEFT);

        query.select(mediaRoot);

        requestedFields.forEach((field, subFields) -> {
            if (Utils.isJoinableField(mediaRoot, field)) {
                Join<Object, Object> join = mediaRoot.join(field, JoinType.LEFT);
                subFields.forEach(subField -> join.fetch(subField, JoinType.LEFT));
            } else {
                mediaRoot.get(field);
            }
        });

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (category != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(mediaRoot.get("mediaCategory").get("id"), category));
        }

        List<Predicate> namePredicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(mediaRoot.get("name"), "%" + name + "%"));
        }
        if (alternativeTitle != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(altTitlesJoin.get("name"), "%" + alternativeTitle + "%"));
        }

        if (!namePredicates.isEmpty()) {
            Predicate orPredicate = cb.or(namePredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
            predicates.add(orPredicate);
        }

        if (!predicates.isEmpty()) {
            query.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        }

        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}

MediaModel class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "medias", indexes = {@Index(name = "idx_name_media", columnList = "name_media", unique = true)})
@Getter
@Setter
public class MediaModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_media")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name_media")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "episode_count")
    private Integer totalEpisodes;

    @Column(name = "episode_length_in_minutes")
    private Integer episodeLength;

    @Column(name = "about", length = 10000)
    private String about;

    @Column(name = "url_cover")
    private String cover;

    @Column(name = "url_banner")
    private String banner;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_category", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private MediaCategoryModel mediaCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "media", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotNull
    private List<ExternalReferenceModel> externalReference;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "medias_has_companies",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "medias_id_media"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "companies_id_company"))
    private List<CompanyModel> company;

    // ...
}

For example if I Query Media requesting id, name, about and I print ou look into debug all fields of the class as filled. I already have tried with EAGER, but the result are the same.

Well you are returning a MediaModel so it will automatically bind and select all fields. You would need to return a Map containing the fields instead of your entity. Next to that you would need your criteria to return only the fields you want and not the full entity (as you are doing now).

On second thought you might be able to achieve your needs with multiselect on the criteria to get hte partially filled entity.

Thanks @M.Deinum. Using query.multselect I would have to use Tuples and Reflection?

Why would you need reflection? You still should be able to link it to your regular objects (I would suggest the documentation and some searching).
